# Unmarshalling an XmlType for unit testing in Java

Tags: java, web-services, junit, jaxb

I am writing an Java class that takes the output of a web service and populates a bean.  The service returns XML which is converted to a Java object by JAXB generated code.  To unit test this, I want to create XML fragments for the individual parts and convert them to their corresponding objects for testing.

The JAXB class starts:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ItemDef", namespace = "http://localhost/schema", propOrder = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
})
public class ItemDef {
```

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item xmlns="http://localhost/schema">
</Item>
```

And the following Java code:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ItemDef.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
ItemDef item = (ItemDef) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

Resulting in the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://localhost/schema", local:"Item"). Expected elements are (none)
```

I've tried different variations on the name so that doesn't appear to be the issue.  I think the problem is that `ItemDef` is a type and an `@XmlType` and not an `@XmlElement`.  Is there a way I can get JAXB to accept this partial component?

Comment: Did you try this as the XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemDef xmlns="http://localhost/schema">
</ItemDef>

Answer (score 0):

You missed @XmlRootElement(name="Item",namespace="http://localhost/schema") annotation on top of ItemDef

Answer (score 0):

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation can handle this use case if you use one of the `unmarshal` methods that takes a class parameter.

```
ItemDef itemDef = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source,ItemDef.class).getValue();
```

Comment: This is working to successfully create the class (after reworking so `source` is the document element and not the file).  Unfortunately, all the properties are coming up as null.  I'm not getting any exceptions and I've confirmed that the document element isn't coming as null, so I'm not sure what is preventing it from populating.

Comment: @BrianNickel - Can you update your question to include the full source for `ItemDef` and the the XML you are trying to unmarshal?  There currently isn't enough information to figure out what might be going wrong.